# Retaining superscript formatting on on .PasteSpecial

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, copy-paste, superscript

I am copying a range from one workbook to another. As much of the data in the source range is a formula I need to paste by value:

```
With TargetRange
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
```

The problem is the xlPasteValue destroys the superscript formatting in (static) cells. How can I do a paste by value which retains the superscript formatting?

I can just re-paste by xlPasteAll those static cells with superscript formatting but this is a bit of a kludge and is not terribly maintainable.

Comment: There's no simple solution to this, short of looping through the copied range after running your paste values and then copying over all the static cells (or testing for sub/superscript and only copying those, but that's going to be slower, depending on the amount of data you have)

Answer (score 2):

copy pasting functionality is either on the total object of the cell as a range or on certain properties. One of the range.font properties is superscript, so if this is applied to the COMPLETE cell it will be listed here and passed on as past of the text formatting.

Now there is also the possibility to only apply font formatting to a limited set of characters in the cell. This "feature" of setting formats for individual text characters isn't a direct range property, however it is a property of the Characters in the range (or cell). Now this is a messy thing to deal with.

See here a bit of code from recording the application of superscript to a subset of characters:

```
With rTest.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=2).Font
    .Superscript = True
End With
With rTest.Characters(Start:=3, Length:=2).Font
    .Subscript = False
End With
```

If you look at your (locals) watch window you will observe that the characters property isn't listed. See here what Microsoft says about this for Office 2012:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198232%28v=office.14%29.aspx

> "The Characters object isn't a collection."

In short: what you want would mean to identify the cells with this "feature" and `xlPasteAll` for these. The character property cannot be interrogated via VBA as it seems.

Comment: To your last point: Yes it can - it's quite straightforward to determine which (if any) characters in a cell have sub/superscript applied, just by looping through each character and checking its `.Font.Subscript` or `.Font.Superscript` property.

Comment: sorry for the convusing comment, agreed Tim Williams, what I meant is there is no possibility on the level of the cell/range object